# Absolute Positioning with percentages & responsive

Tags: css, absolute

I have a div with a box inside:

```
<div class="grid-image" id="grid-1">
  <div class="grid-box">
     <h2>SAMPLE TEXT</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the box to be 50% width of its parent, but i need it to be absolutely positioned in the center of the parent

```
.grid-image {
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
    background-size:cover;
    position:relative;
}

.grid-box {
    border:5px #FFF solid;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:50%;
    right:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-25% -25% 0 0;
}

.grid-box h2 {
    color:#FFF;
    padding:15px 10px;
    letter-spacing:5px;
}
```

This approach doesn't seem to work, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Do you want it to have `50%` __height__ also?

Comment: Absolutely-positioned elements have their own layout context, so they have no idea how big the parent element is. Why do you need absolute positioning if all you want to do is center the element?

Comment: @Diodeus they do have idea. If you set `50%` width for the `.grid-box` it will actually take the `50%` from the `.grid-image` but only if the `.grid-image` has fixed width value (not %)

Comment: doesnt have to be absolutely positioned... i just need it to sit in the middle somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created this for sometime back. **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/magnus16/pen/GKcem)** Check 1st div.

and this will work for any width and height, not just 50%

```
.absolute-positioned-div{
    height:50%;
    width:50%;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're assuming that the `.grid-box` has to be `50%` width of its parent then position it in `25%` from the left. It's clear math

```
.grid-box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Just make sure that the `.grid-image` has a fixed width - not percentage.

**Also** notice that the computed dimensions of an element are the sum of `width`, `margin`, `border` and `padding`. So if you set `50%` width and `25%` left you'll actually get `75%` of the parent **plus** any additional border, margin and padding.